# Installing Ubuntu on a GPT HDD

Tags: installation, partitioning, uefi

I have changed my system to boot from UEFI instead of BIOS and have installed Windows 7 on my internal SSD which has GPT partition type.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my external HDD. My machine is a Lenovo [W520](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?DocID=PD015362). My HDD is a 1TB USB3 [WD](http://support.wdc.com/product/install.asp?groupid=215&lang=en).

Here is some of what I have been trying:

1. My laptop is set to boot in UEFI mode.
2. I have 64 bit version of Ubuntu, on my bootable flash disk
3. I took out my SSD before installing Ubuntu
4. Before installation my external HDD was also partitioned as GPT and it only had one 950GB partition
5. I tried two different methods:

   - **First:** When I let the Ubuntu to install itself automatically,
     without changing anything, the installation completed but Ubuntu did
     not boot. SSD was out and I am sure the systems boots in UEFI mode.
   - **Second**: I tried to do the partitioning myself in the following order, but I still have the same problem, I am sure my HDD is
     partitioned as GPT:

     - `/EFI Boot`
     - `/(root)`
     - `/swap`
     - `/home`

I chose to install the bootloader in `/EFI boot`.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

**Update:**  I was sure that Windows, on SSD, boots in UEFI mode. However, I disconnected my HDD and the windows did boot from SSD.I used the live USB to boot Ubuntu and let it do the partitioning and install Ubuntu on the external HDD. I still had the same problem and Ubuntu did not boot. Then I used the live USB and installed Boot-Repair. After running Boot-repair and a restart everything was good, and Ubuntu did boot from HDD. However, there is a line before booting into Ubuntu: `ata_id[279]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument` But the system boots.

**Boot Info Script:** Here is a [Boot Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5673325/) I got after using Boot Repair.

I tried to change the partitioning and partition sizes. After reading [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html), I changed the partitioning using Gparted.
I also installed the bootloader in `/dev/sda1` which is flagged as the `/boot` partition. As expected after installation and a reboot, Ubuntu did not boot. So by following [this](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181742/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-12-on-a-64bit-pc-with-uefi-and-gpt-ssd-disk-with-no-cur) posts, I tried to register the bootloader to the EFI. But I was not successful. I even noticed that my machine might have [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181742/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-12-on-a-64bit-pc-with-uefi-and-gpt-ssd-disk-with-no-cur) problem, and I changed the `/EFI/Ubuntu/bootx64.efi` name and location but no effect, Ubuntu did not want to boot. 
Again, I used boot repair to solve the boot problem and it worked like the previous time and I am in Ubuntu. But I really like to know what is causing this problem. The interesting thing is that Boot Repair has created all possible folders and files. Is there a way that I know which folders are being used for boot? These are the different folders and files:
  -`/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi`
  -`/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` and `bootx64.efi`
  -`/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/bootx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Grub2/installer does not always manage EFI. Best option is to boot the live CD and use boot repair.

See : [How do I install Windows 7 alongside a pre-existing Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation)

Different question, same solution.

Post the url bootrepair gives you if it does not work.