# Does ubuntu install on GPT hard drive?

Tags: installation

I recently tried to install window 7, downgrading from windows 8 but the hard drive rejected the os, telling me that GPT hdd does not support win7. I was wondering if Ubuntu can be installed instead for now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu supports both "MSDOS"-style partition tables and GPT partition tables.

If Secure Boot is also enabled, and you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, [see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).

If you just want to install Ubuntu by itself, then you shouldn't have to do anything special, even if you have a GPT disk. See [this generic installation question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and [these generic instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

Although this works most of the time, sometimes the GRUB boot loader will not be installed correctly. So if you cannot boot after installing, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/296853/22949) or the [techniques presented here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) (they apply to this situation, even though this situation is not a recent installation of Windows).

Alternatively, if Ubuntu will be the only OS you want on your machine (or all the OSes you want on your machine will work without UEFI and GPT), then you may consider disabling EFI in your "BIOS" setup and creating an MS-DOS style partition table on your disk.